# getting "exc_bad_access code=2"

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi, I am developing iPhone application and using `NSCalendar` class,have taken an currentMonth of `NSDate` type. I am getting the `"exc_bad_access code=2"` error.

I have used the following code:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [gregorian components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit)fromDate:[NSDate date]];
currentMonth = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:currentMonth options:0];
```

So can anybody help me to solve problem.

Comment: Post the complete stacktrace of the crash.

Comment: Also what type is `currentMonth`? The name suggests an `int` but it's being assigned from a method that returns `NSDate`, so I'm surprised it even compiles.

Comment: its not displaying any exception or any contents in stacktrace

Comment: OK, voting to close as there is too little information to resolve the issue.